# Include top level entity ID on all levels of nested children

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In my application I am planning to have several nested entities that contain several levels of nested objects with the top level object being my universal user type.

I want each of the nested entities to contain the ID of the top level entity to make querying much simpler but in documentation it is only showing parent/child relationship so I am not sure how I should structure it in Entityframework core so the top level entity ID is included in every entity.

I wrote this simple class structure to show what you I mean.  Is this the correct way of doing it so that cascade delete will still work correctly?

```
public class AppUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // .. various entity specific properties
    public AppUserTypeA AppUserTypeA { get; set; }
}

public class AppUserTypeA
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // .. various entity specific properties

    public Profile Profile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AppUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AppUserId))]
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // .. various entity specific properties

    public ICollection<ProfileElement> ProfileElements { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AppUserTypeAId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AppUserTypeAId))]
    public AppUserTypeA AppUserTypeA { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AppUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AppUserId))]
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // .. various entity specific properties

    [Required]
    public string ProfileId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProfileId))]
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AppUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AppUserId))]
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can apply the properties of `AppUser` to all entities by making it the base class, and derive from it on the other classes `public class AppUserTypeA : AppUser { ... }` but of course multiple inheritance is not supported so there is no way to do `public class Profile : AppUserTypeA, AppUser { .. }` this can be worked around, but your reference to nesting is muddying the waters a bit on a solution. If you could clarify:: what do you expect your nested entities to look like in the SQL tables?

Comment: I really just want to have `AppUserId` on every entity so I can pull back tables based on it without any joins.  I guess it could just be a regular string property i fill out when creating the record.  I am just wondering if that will come back to bite me in the ass later if I have to re-assign objects from one user to another user.  Would that be easier if I had navigation property there also?  I am not confident in database design

Comment: Don't fret the database design. EF takes the worry out. Create new migrations often when changing your schema, it's very easy to revert.

Comment: So I took a minute to think about what you're trying to accomplish, and basically you're trying to add the `AppUser`'s Id into each table, which is really going against the grain on SQL's main strength which is relational mapping. It will indeed come back to bite you, because where `Cascading Delete` is a thing, there isn't a `Cascading Update` which means changes in one table would require you to update all tables. That is not what you want.

Comment: so it would be better as independent string or better as foreign key and then disable cascade?

Comment: I started thinking about what would happen if I wanted to re-assign an entity to a different user and either way I will still have to loop through entities to update it.  I think the only real benefit of the foreign key is that if a user ID changes then all records will update correctly and maybe will provide some useful errors if entities are not re-assigned correctly.